# Fourth Order Homogeneous Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Finding the homogenous solution for Y'''' - B^4Y = 0.

The roots I found are ±B and ±Bi, so the solution I got was

Y=C<sub>1</sub>e<sup>Bx</sup>+C<sub>2</sub> e<sup>-Bx</sup>+C<sub>3</sub> sin(Bx)+C<sub>4</sub> cos(Bx)

I got the same result when using Wolfram Alpha. However, the paper that I am reading gives the answer

Y=C<sub>1</sub>cosh(Bx)+C<sub>2</sub>sinh(Bx)+C<sub>3</sub>cos(bx)+C<sub>4</sub>sin(bx).

[Here is the image from the paper.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUrOJ.png) Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same (provided the coefficients can be complex). It's just a matter of choice of basis for the same space. For example $C_1=1,C_2=0,C_3=0,C_4=0$ in the second one corresponds to $C_1=1/2,C_2=1/2,C_3=0,C_4=0$ in the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still a highschool student trying doing this for a derivation and I just learnt about all this stuff today. Sorry If I'm asking an obvious question.

Comment: It's weird how `sinh` and `cosh` are rarely, if ever, mentioned in school, but computer algebra systems *love* using them for some reason.